# returning local variable from the plugin_path how i can chage it

Tags: c, pointers, char

Sir I Used String Concatenation process what I think if there is filename as “plugin1” then in that file “plugin1.dll” will be there so I concatenate the string in the such way that output will be “C://DataViz//plugin1//plugin1.dll” then using simple fopen function i check whether there is file in that given path or not if not then “return NULL” or return “path”.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* plugin_path(char filename);

int main(){
    char *path;
    char filename[] = "plugin";
    
    path = plugin_path(filename);
    printf("%s", path);
    return 0;
}

char* plugin_path(char filename){
    char plugin[] = "C:\\data\\";
    char plugin1;
    char *str = plugin1;
    
    strcat(plugin, filename);
    strcat(plugin," \\ ");
    strcat(plugin, filename);
    strcat(plugin,".dll");
    
    return str;
  }
```

will you please help me with above code

Comment: Besides the problems with memory size and lifetime of your variable that were already addressed in an answer, why would you want to include spaces around `" \\ "` in your path? That would require the directory to contain a trailing space in its name which is very unlikely.

Comment: i am working on the dll file and i need the path to load the plugin.dll so for that i use "\\"

Comment: I understand why you need `\\\` but why the spaces before and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allocate enough size for new string and return the pointer to the allocated region.

Also you should use `const char*`, not `char`, for the argument to receive a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* plugin_path(const char* filename);

int main(){
    char *path;
    char filename[] = "plugin";
    
    path = plugin_path(filename);
    printf("%s", path);
    free(path);
    return 0;
}

char* plugin_path(const char* filename){
    char plugin[] = "C:\\data\\";
    const char* part1 = " \\ ";
    const char* part2 = ".dll";
    /* +1 for terminating null-character */
    char *str = malloc(strlen(plugin) + strlen(filename) * 2 + strlen(part1) + strlen(part2) + 1);
    
    strcpy(str, plugin);
    strcat(str, filename);
    strcat(str, part1);
    strcat(str, filename);
    strcat(str, part2);
    
    return str;
}
```